# MainPage.OnStart() No Suitable Method Found to Override

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to run the following in my MainPage.cs:

```cs
public class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    //...

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best);
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
        Position position = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();
        var f = await geocoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(position);

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(",", f));
        Debug.WriteLine("exeuctie");
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the error `MainPage.OnStart() No Suitable Method Found to Override`.

My app was building fine until I added the OnStart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentPage` does not have an `OnStart` method; only `Application` has `OnStart`.

You can use `OnAppearing` on a `ContentPage`. This code will trigger each time the `ContentPage` appears on the screen:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best);
    var location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request);
    Position position = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();
    var f = await geocoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(position);

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(",", f));
    Debug.WriteLine("exeuctie");
}
```

Comment: Whoops, my bad.